# google oauth2 api connection refused

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am using the Google API libraries for server-to-server communication in a web application we've been building.  It works on our development, and test servers, however, when we move the application to production, the Curl commands result in connection refused when attempting to get an Oauth2 token.

On our dev, and test servers:

curl -v https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

is successful, and returns the full 405 response

On our production server, the curl command results in

```
curl -v https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token         
* About to connect() to accounts.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 216.58.216.205... Connection refused
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4009:808::200d... Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4009:808::200d: Network is unreachable
* Success
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4009:808::200d: Network is unreachable
```

Is google blacklisting our site, or something?  All these servers are on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was, in fact our DMZ firewall blocking the outgoing request

Answer (score 0):

This has solved my problem:

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```